# Prevent Login via Multiple browsers on same machine

Tags: jsf-2.2, session-scope

I have gone through the questions asked by others regarding it; but still I did nt get my answer.
I simply want to prevent a user from logging in using multiple browsers on same machine
One way is to use a separate field in Database to check whether user is still logged in
but this will only help when the user deliberately logs Out;
but if in case the browser gets closed so how I m going to make it work??
I m using JSF session scoped bean for maintaining session.
Or tell me if there is a  way to call some method exactly before session invalidates in JSF??
Thank you!

Comment: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Keyword: Browser fingerprint.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get it